Failed to load module script (vue.js & express)
My frontend is Vue.js
and I build it
and run it with express.js
but I get this error
index.9235fea6.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I don't know what to do

There are typically two ways for fixing it:

Server routing
In your Express server, you should have something like:
app.use(express.static('path-to-your-dist-folder'));


Correct file path If Express can't find your index.9235fea6.js file, it might be returning an HTML error page, which is causing the problem



  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});```

If you write this, you will get the same error as in the text.

and if you don't write it,
the page will keep loading.
